# Why does the amr field of the JWT token returned by MSAL sometimes have wia or mfa?

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal, msal.js

I have an app that is authenticating to the MS Graph in an Azure AD tenant and I'm using MSAL to call `acquireTokenSilent`. Sometimes my app receives a JWT access token with the amr field containing mfa, specifically:

```
amr: [
  "pwd",
  "rsa",
  "mfa"
 ]
```

which results in a successful OBO token exchange.

A couple of times my app has received a JWT access token with the amr field containing wia:

```
amr: [
  "wia"
 ]
```

and attempts to exchange this token for OBO token fail.

I haven't made any code changes in the authentication code in my app. What causes the difference in `acquireTokenSilent` behavior?

Thanks!

**Edit**

The app is an SPA written in TypeScript with ReactJS. We require the user to login with AAD before loading any of the content and the app calls `loginRedirect` to our tenant authority in the `componentDidMount` React method to achieve this.

When the user initiates a call to an authorized source (a middle-tier service we wrote), the app calls acquireTokenSilent to get a token with scopes for the middle-tier service's configure API. It then makes a call to our middle-tier service and sends the token in the header with the Bearer prefix. That service exchanges the token for an OBO token.

We have an AAD app registration in the Azure portal that has delegated API permissions to the AAD Graph User.Read and to our middle-tier service's configure API.

The middle-tier service receives the token (that we got from the app's `acquireTokenSilent` call) and exchanges it for an OBO token, requesting permission for several scopes for the MS Graph and `requested_token_use=on_behalf_of`.

When the JWT access token received from acquireTokenSilent has the `amr` field containing `wia`, the token exchange on the middle-tier service gets an error about a conditional access claims challenge requiring MFA.

Answer (score 4):

`amr` is the [Authentication Methods Reference](http://self-issued.info/docs/draft-jones-oauth-amr-values-00.html) claim in the JWT. `pwd` refers to password authentication, by the service (using a client secret) or user and `wia` is Windows integrated auth.

Would need to know more about your set-up, like what platform are you using, what is your overall scenario, and how are you setting up the client application and making the acquire token calls, in order to determine the difference you are seeing between the calls.

You can checkout this [.NET sample on OBO](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-native-aspnetcore-v2/tree/master/2.%20Web%20API%20now%20calls%20Microsoft%20Graph) and find more [info here](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/wiki/on-behalf-of#how-to-call-obo) on MSAL.NET and OBO. More [info on OBO flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-on-behalf-of-flow).

Comment: Thanks @Jenny. I edit my original question and added more info about my scenario. Does that help or do you need more info?